# Cloudinary Video uploading error Entity too large up to 300MB

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-5, video-upload

I am using Cloudinary by using library "https://github.com/jrm2k6/cloudder" but when I upload large video files greater than 100MB it shows "Entity too large: error, I am using apache server.
Also try Cloudinary upload_large function but show same error.

```
    Cloudder::uploadVideo($tmpFilePath,null, ['resource_type' => 'video','chunk_size' => 60000000000]);
    $response = Cloudder::getResult();
```

Resulted error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your upload_max_file_zize in php.ini is allowed to upload more then 100MB go ahead and update your upload_file_size to whatever you would like!

Comment: The error appears to come from the API side here, and not from the OP’s own system.

Comment: i have change upload_max_file_size =1024 mb but resulted same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make chunk size 6000000:

```
Cloudder::upload_large($tmpFilePath,null, ['resource_type' => 'video',"eager_async" => TRUE, "eager" => ["format"=>"mp4","width"=>1280, "height"=>720, "crop"=>"limit", "duration"=>"7200p"], 'chunk_size' => 6000000]);
```

Answer (score 0):

On the free plan Cloudinary's API only allows a max video size of 100MB.  It's 10MB for images and raw files.  There is no way around this except to:

1. shrink your source file so that it is below the threshold
2. pay for a better plan, the next level up allows 2GB of video and 20MB of raw file / image.